# Rightbarbuttonitem displayed on left side during transition (dismiss)

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I currently have an app with 2 view controllers inside a navigation controller.
They are pushed in this order:
A, B

A has an empty (but displayed) navigation bar  and B has a navigation bar with:

1) A title view
2) A custom leftBarButtonItem.

This is the initialisation code:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.addFavoriteButton]; // addFavorite is an IBOutlet to a view outside the view hierarchy of my VC.
```

When I go back from B to A, either by panning from the left or touching the back button, the right button is displayed in a weird position on the left of the screen during the transition.

The B layout is similarly used for a C view controller, without any issue.

You can see a screenshot from the botched transition:
[image]
As you can see, the heart (my right button) is wrongly displayed.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

My button had a constraint, removing it fixed the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue. What was the particular constraint that you removed? This is only not working for me on iOS <= 9.

Comment: @JeremyHicks sorry, I don't remember. Look for errors in your console, maybe this would help. Paste any error to https://www.wtfautolayout.com

Comment: This also happened to me when animating a layoutIfNeeded() call while dismissing the VC